# How can i refresh my panel content, when i click to command button?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I dynamically create my panels, I want to edit them with dialogBox. I can update database all works fine, but the view is not updated:
This is my dialogBox with the command button "submitDialog":

```
        <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Add Memo" widgetVar="dialogMemo" resizable="false" >
        <h:form id="formDialog">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
                <h:outputLabel for="commentInput" value="Comment:" />  
                <p:inputTextarea id="commentInput" value="#{dashboardBean.currentComment}" rows="6" cols="25" label="commentInput" required="true"/>
                <p:watermark for="commentInput" value="Enter your memo..."/>  
                <h:outputLabel for="selectShare" value="Share Memo: " />  
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectShare" /> 

                <h:outputLabel for="choosePriority" value="Priority:" />  
                <p:selectOneMenu id="choosePriority" value="#{dashboardBean.currentPriority}" label="choosePriority">  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Low Priority" itemValue="1" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Medium Priority" itemValue="2" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="High Priority" itemValue="3" />  
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:commandButton id="submitDialog" icon="ui-icon-check" value="Confirm" ajax='false' type="submit"/>
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="dialogMemo.hide();" value="Cancel"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

and my panels are added to "dashboardId":

```
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit id="leftPanel" position="west" size="250" header="My Memos" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">
            <h:form id="form"> 
                <p:commandButton id="addMemo" icon="ui-icon-plus" onclick="dialogMemo.show();" type="submit" action="#{dashboardBean.getEditControl}"/>  
                <p:dashboard id="dashboardId" model="#{dashboardBean.model}" binding="#{dashboardBean.dashboard}">
                </p:dashboard>  
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
```

I try to solve this problem, when i open dialogBox, i set update attribute to my commandButton   "submitDialog" with panel id:

```
public void handleEdit(ActionEvent actionEvent)
{
    UIComponent component = actionEvent.getComponent().getParent().getParent();
    String id = component.getId();

    UIViewRoot view = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    CommandButton button = (CommandButton) view.findComponent("formDialog:submitDialog");
    button.setUpdate(":form:" + id);
}
```

The database is modified correctly, the page is reloaded but my panel is NOT updated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by editing directly the HtmlOutputText of my panel.